# PHP preg_replace on SEO URL not giving expected results

Tags: php, url, seo, preg-replace, character

So, I have this method:

```
$seo_special = array("ä", "õ", "ö", "ü", "Ä", "Õ", "Ö", "Ü");
$seo_special_replace = array("a", "o", "o", "u", "a", "o", "o", "u");
$seo_tag_a2b = str_replace($seo_special, $seo_special_replace, $row->name);
$seo_tag_a2b = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]/i', '', strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', trim($seo_tag_a2b))));
```

And I expect it to replace special characters to normal ones, but somehow, it skips those characters and the result for **Põrandalaud / Liistparkett** is **prandalaud--liistparkett** when it should be **porandalaud--liistparkett** and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to translit weird characters to ASCII only chars.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    if( !empty($replace) ) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

    return $clean;
}
```

Test:

```
echo toAscii("Mess'd up --text-- just (to) stress /test/ ?our! `little` \\clean\\ url fun.ction!?-->");
returns: messd-up-text-just-to-stress-test-our-little-clean-url-function

echo toAscii("Perché l'erba è verde?", "'"); // Italian
returns: perche-l-erba-e-verde

echo toAscii("Peux-tu m'aider s'il te plaît?", "'"); // French
returns: peux-tu-m-aider-s-il-te-plait

echo toAscii("Tänk efter nu – förr'n vi föser dig bort"); // Swedish
returns: tank-efter-nu-forrn-vi-foser-dig-bort

echo toAscii("ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ");
returns: aaaaaaaeceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyssaaaaaaaeceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy

echo toAscii("Custom`delimiter*example", array('*', '`'));
returns: custom-delimiter-example

echo toAscii("My+Last_Crazy|delimiter/example", '', ' ');
returns: my last crazy delimiter example
```

Method and credits to [The perfect PHP clean url generator](http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator)

And to assist you with googling, you can search for 'url slug php'.

Comment: All that code was got with googling already, actually even tried around 7 alternatives, never knew that the problem was with the file encoding. Doing that for joomla 1x because client does not want to update and apparently joomla 1x's files are in ASCII not in UTF-8

Comment: This function does the job. But you don't have to use LC_ALL - it is enough with LC_COLLATE

Answer (score 0):

It could be a mismatch between your PHP source file's character encoding and that of the string you are processing.

Make sure the two of them match. If you're working on UTF-8 data, you need to make sure the PHP file is stored in UTF-8 as well. Otherwise, the special characters will have other byte values and not match those in `$row->name`.